# Qt QML QQuick Application Print Dialog needs a pointer to parent widget

Tags: qt, printing, qml

Opening a QPrintDialog needs a pointer to parent widget but:
I have a QQuickApplication that is based on QGuiApplication that is QCoreApplication extend for non Widget apps.
My app window cannot be interpreted as a Widget. so is there any way?
I wonder why there is no QML type of this facility!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the signature is

```
QPrintDialog(QPrinter *printer, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
```

indicating that **the `parent` argument is optional**. So

```
QPrintDialog myPrintDialog(myPrinter);
```

is totally fine.

Comment: Thanks my dear. I didn't see that is optional :)
I got Available printers and exposed the list to QML.

Comment: I'm glad if I could help. If my answer solves your problem you can mark it as "accepted".